# How do I merge Angular frontend and Node backend in one git repository?

Tags: node.js, angular, git

I have an Angular frontend project in one repo and a local backend node project (currently not in a repo). I want to be able to work on both at the same time so having them in the same git repo would make it way easier to share changes.

My problem is I don't know which files need to move and which files can stay at the root. There are plenty of Angular, IDE, Node, and git files/folders and I have no idea where to start. I need to host both locally and eventually deploy.

Any tips on how to actually go about this? My current structure is below:

**frontend**
[image: frontend]

**backend**
[image]

Comment: This question is hard to answer without information about your file structure. In general you can create two folders: one for backend code and second for Angular code and store it in git repository.

Comment: thank you for your answer @kadash. I can't just copy paste everything from the current repo into a folder, and then paste the backend folder into a the git though right?

Comment: I would recommend a mono-repo provider. nx.dev has angular flavors you could run through in a quick tutorial. If you just want both backend and frontend directories in the same repo, you just put both those folders in a root folder, and initialize git tracking from there, don’t mix dependencies or configurations between the two projects without knowing what you’re doing. If you want a root package file to run the two projects, don’t install dependencies there, but add scripts with —prefix to install and run nested package.json scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to store everything in one repository and still have git history of frontend app:

1. Create `frontend` folder in root of the frontend repository and move all folders and files into it besides .git folder and .gitignore file
2. Create `backend` folder in root of the frontend repository and paste there content of backend code files
3. In root of the repository git add everything and git commit all and git push it to repository

Comment: do I move node_modules as well? or can I just combine them from both projects at the root? @kadash

Comment: I think it will be better to have separate package.json (node_modules) for backend and frontend code. btw node_modules should be in gitignored and only package.json and package.lock.json pushed to the repository.